# How to combine two simple sql queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following sql query(s):

```
//Get id
SELECT id from magazine where name = 'Web Designer'


SELECT avatar from person where newsletter = 1 and id in
(
 SELECT person_id as id FROM person_magazine WHERE magazine_id = 9 //use id from previous query
)
```

How do I combine them so I don't have to run two queries?

Comment: did you try replacing 9 with: (YOUR FIRST QUERY HERE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to learn about joins.  The following is the query you really seem to want:

```
SELECT p.avatar
from person p join
     person_magazine pm
     on pm.person_id = p.id join
     magazine m
     on pm.magazine_id = m.id
where p.newsletter = 1 and m.name = 'Web Designer'
```

Comment: Lovely stuff.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nest the queries:

```
SELECT avatar 
from person 
where 
    newsletter = 1 
    and id in (
        SELECT person_id as id 
        FROM person_magazine 
        WHERE magazine_id = (SELECT id from magazine where name = 'Web Designer' limit 1)
    )
```

Or use a variable:

```
set @mag_id = (SELECT id from magazine where name = 'Web Designer' limit 1);
SELECT avatar from person where newsletter = 1 and id in
(
    SELECT person_id as id FROM person_magazine WHERE magazine_id = @mag_id
)
```

I use `limit 1` to ensure that only one row is returned.

If there are more rows, consider using `join`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is only one entry for a person and for a magazine name in person_magazine table.

```
SELECT avatar 
  FROM person P
 INNER JOIN  person_magazine PM
    ON P.id = pm.person_id
 INNER JOIN magazine M
    ON PM.magazine_id = M.id
 WHERE P.newsletter = 1
   AND PM.name = 'Web Designer'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT avatar FROM person p
       INNER JOIN  person_magazine p_m ON p.id = p_m.person_id
       WHERE p.newsletter = 1
       AND p_m.name = 'Web Designer'
```